# Can i read what did i already wrote in a cell in Xlsxwriter?

Tags: python-3.x, xlsxwriter

i was trying to find a way to read what i wrote in cells before i `workbook.close()` and save everything, i was checking the Xlsxwriter docs for a way but couldn't find any.

i did wrote this function but i was only able to check if the cell or cells is empty or already been wrote

```html
def cell_empty(row, columstart, columend=None):
    empty = False
    types = ['String', 'Blank', 'Number']
    if columend is None:
        try:
            if any(typ in str(worksheet.table[row][columstart]) for typ in types):
                empty = False
        except KeyError:
            empty = True

    if columend is not None:
        for y in range(columstart, columend):
            try:
                if any(typ in str(worksheet.table[row][columstart]) for typ in types):
                    empty = False
            except KeyError:
                empty = True
```

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

That isn't supported by XlsxWriter.

I wrote XlsxWriter and my view was/is that it shouldn't be treated as a database since it was never designed with that in mind.

If you need to track the data that you are writing you should track it in your application where you have full access to the data.

Comment: Thank you sir! I'm in situation where is very hard to track the data in the application.